# EntityManager.find not retunring values

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

i m new to JPA and i'm using eclipseLink as my Implementation.

i am trying to get a package from my Database with id = 11.

```
Package p1 = null;
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
p1 = em.find(Package.class, id);
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();


EclipseLinks' SQL log delivers correct SQL.
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-11-03 14:48:59.711--ServerSession(538471155)--Connection(174248886)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])

--SELECT ID, depth, length, weight, width, counrty, street, zip FROM Packages WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [11]
```

executing this sql, manually replacing ? with 11, delivers the correct row. what am i missing?

Ps.
The query for all records is working fine, same instance of entitymanager is used.
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Package p");

Thanks in advance

pps.

```
em.getTransaction().begin();

        p1 = em.find(Package.class, id);
        if(p1 != null) {
            log.log(level.INFO, "not null");
        }
        else {
            log.log(level.INFO, "null");
        }
        em.flush();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
```

logs not null, packagedata is present and correct. i can log even aver em.close(), everything seems to be in order.

as soon as i

```
return p1;
```

functions from outside cannto acces the data anymore

FINAL EDIT:

SOMEHOW log.log(Level.INFO, "found Package with ID:", p1.getId()); is not writting anything past the ":" xD, so sorry^^

Comment: How are you using p1 after this code? How do you tell that JPA doesn't find the package?

Comment: Perhaps you are using wrong schema & eclipselink has created empty tables?

Comment: i am Logging p1.getXY() to the console, nothing i logged. the Schema is present, EclipseLink creates and populates it, i checked^^

Comment: If you're logging p1.getXY() and nothing is logged, then it means that p1 is not null (else you would have a NullPointerException). So p1 has been found, and its XY property is an empty string.

Comment: how can eg; p1.getID() return somethgn empty? I explicitly ask for id 11, the select statement containts a Select ID

Comment: updated my question, the data is present if i inspect the object while debugging, however, logging values form p1 results in emtpy strings

Comment: Well, you found the bug by yourself, so you're probably not as idiot as you think. What was the problem?

Comment: i logged println("log the id", p.getid()), instead of "log the id:" + getid())^^